Can I use a machine washing to clean neoprene wetsuits/socks/hoods/gloves if I use cold water, no spinning, no bleach and a gentle detergent?
I was looking for the proper way to wash neoprene wetsuits and I read on How to wash and care for your neoprene:

it’s best to avoid machine-washing neoprene as the washer can harm the fabric.

Can I use a machine washing to clean neoprene wetsuits/socks/hoods/gloves if I use cold water, no spinning, no bleach and a gentle detergent?
I read that spinning can damage the seams of a wetsuit, but I could configure the washing machine not to spin. I also read that washing neoprene in hot water can reduce its flexibility but I can use cold water. I read that bleach can degrade the physical structure of neoprene and cause discoloration but I don't have to use bleach.
Lastly, I read in the article Wetsuit Care: It Isn’t All About Washing Neoprene that

The detergents used in washing machines are strong detergents with abrasive chemicals that are forbidden for your neoprene.

But I could use the mild detergents as for hand washing.

Probably depends on the specifics of the particular washing machine. Mine, on cold-water delicate cycle with a few other settable options might do OK. My old one - no way.

Not neoprene suits but I've killed 2 high end goretex vests using washing machines, recommended wash and low temp.  I would not attempt it myself and would stick to handwashing.

@ItalianPhilosopher Thanks. Killed due to spinning?

@ItalianPhilosopher note that neoprene is designed to stretch, GoreTex isn't, so it's very different.

What do you mean with "neoprene suit"? It's certainly a bad idea to put a neoprene swim racing suit into a washer. Those are so fragile that you shouldn't even touch them with a finger nail.

I am not sure what phase nuked them.  The part that failed was the cinch zipper around the waist.  I am not saying neoprene == goretex.  I am saying that I would be very very leery in putting expensive exotic fabrics into a washing machine because my usage did seem to stick to manufacturer recommendations.  If I had to redo, I'd put them within a pillowcase or the like.  I put plenty of things in dishwashers and washing machines in general and totally ignore warnings on fragile dishes for example, so don't count me as generally overcautious here.

I do, with the settings pretty much as you say (or even a very gentle spin). 20 or even 30 C shouldn't be an issue either - it can get that warm in use, especially if you take it off under a running shower, which is normal for some people.
As for detergent, I got a bottle of "wetsuit/drysuit shampoo" with my drysuit. That's meant for handwashing but works in the machine, used sparingly.
To give an idea of how much margin you have, I have a pair of wetsuit shorts, and I just chuck them in the machine with other sportswear on a normal wash and proper spin. They haven't suffered for it. But they're not worth much and I wouldn't risk it with my full wetsuit.

I used to put my wetsuit into a spinning dryer in a caving hut without any visible problem. Until I was too clumsy when stopping the dryer with a stick and tore the wet suit a little bit, but that is just because the old dryer did not have a working brake and I did not want to wait.

@VladimirFГероямслава caving is already pretty harsh on kit. A wetsuit used in more benign environments might take more damage from rough washing.  But you're right that I'm being cautious

Given that your body temperature is (hopefully!) around 37° C, I’d say it can easily get warmer than 20–30° C even before you get in the water, particularly if you’re swimming somewhere where the ambient temperature is also hot.

@JanusBahsJacquet a few degrees cooler for skin temperature, but yes. I hate to think how warm (and sweat-damp) mine got when I cycled in to to swim in a very cold river. The next temperature step on  most machines is 40°C though, and that's warmer than it should get in use - though highly unlikely to be a problem.  For comparison I have base layers than can be washed far hotter, which still fails to get them fresh.
